# Python - check if values are inside objects in list

Tags: python

In something like this

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


li = [Obj(0, 0), Obj(0, 1), Obj(2, 3)]

print(Obj(2,3) in li)
```

I have a False output because even if x and y are the same it counts the object as a different instance. I can remedy using a loop inside the list and checking

```
if(2==o.x and 3==o.y):
    return True
```

Is there some cleaner way to get this without using a loop ?

Comment: Implement an [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method in your class.

Comment: You must define `Obj.__eq__`

Comment: Implement the special methods == and != in your object.

Comment: Alternatively, consider using [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) or the newer [data classes](https://hackernoon.com/a-brief-tour-of-python-3-7-data-classes-22ee5e046517).

Answer (score 0):

Special method for `==` and `!=`:

```
class Obj:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __eq__(self, Object):
        """ == comparison method."""
        return self.x == Object.x and self.y == Object.y

    def __ne__(self, Object):
        """ != comparison method."""
        return not self.__eq__(self, Object)
```

Comment: It depends on each particular case, but it is frequent to add a check like `isinstance(Object, Obj)` or `Object.__class__ == self.__class__` in the implementation of `__eq__` to avoid considering as equals objects of different classes with similarly-named attributes (although sometimes that may be the intended behavior).

Comment: True. Didn't bother with it for the example, but it should be added.

Answer (score 0):

Implement a function `__eq__` like below in your class.

```
def __eq__(self,  x,y):
     if self.x==x and self.y==y:
        return True
```

After that use list comprehension to traverse over the `list` of objects.

`result = any(Obj(2,3) == i for i in obj_list )`